# Divisible Sum Pairs

Tags: java, arrays

Though it will be weird to see this question I really need to understand some core concepts while I continue my journey of coding. I have a problem which is on Hackerrank it goes like [DIVISIBLE SUM PAIRS](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/divisible-sum-pairs/problem)

I will anyhow give the problem statement here:

**Problem Statement**

Given an array, where we have to find the number of pairs divisible by the given number **k**, and there is one more condition to it, which is :
**the arr[i] < arr[j]** from those pairs.

**Example**

For example,  `ar=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `k=5`. Our three pairs meeting the criteria are  `[1,4] [2,3]` and `[4,6]`.

**Code**

Before I publish my code, I would like to tell you that my code has passed all the test cases, and it is accepted to move ahead to the next challenge, but there is a glitch that I'm trying to figure out, which is there in the code.

```
static int divisibleSumPairs(int n, int k, int[] ar) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<ar.length; i++){
      for(int j=i+1; j<ar.length; j++){
            if(((ar[i]+ar[j])%k)==0){
                if(i < j)
                   count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here when I do this `if(i < j) count++`, it gives me the correct result, but as soon as I do this `if(ar[i] < a[j]) count++`, it supposedly gives me a wrong answer.

Can anybody help me clear this out, like what is left? Since I know the check `arr[i] < arr[j]` should give the correct result. I don't want to proceed with the wrong knowledge.

**EDITS**

Since I have understood what I was doing wrong. And I have one edit in my code that is **not starting the inner loop with 1**, since it will start off with 1 every time the inner loop finishes, and again runs. I thank everyone who helped me clear this and made my concepts strong enough to deal with the questions like this.

I personally thank [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans), [Ricola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7424948/ricola), and [xerx593](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592355/xerx593) for clearing out my doubts and giving me the core concepts of looping through the elements. It will help me in the future, and I won't repeat that thing again. :)

Comment: given the arr[i]<arr[j] condition, why are you setting `j=1` each time you run the inner loop, instead of `j=i+1`?

Comment: Isn't it same as `j=1`, and `i=0`, cos anyhow it will be ahead of the `i`, right @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans?

Comment: Very much not, and you can verify this by writing out what the following code does, by hand, on some paper or in a text editor or something: `for (i=0; i<3; i++) { for (j=1; j<3; j++)  { print i + "/" + j; }}`. Start with `i=0`, which pairs will you see printed? Then `i` increments, now which pairs will you see printed?

Comment: Correction to problem:  . . . find the number of pairs whose sum is divisible by the given number k . . .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just checked your link and the condition given in the question statement is

> Find and print the number of (i,j) pairs where i < j  and ar[i] + ar[j] is divisible by k.

Which is simply the number of [unordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_pair) of elements for which the sum is divisible by k.

However you wrote

> there is one more condition to it, which is : the **arr[i] < arr[j]** from
>   those pairs.

I seems like you have misread the question. And it explains why the `i<j` condition works whereas `arr[i] < arr[j]` doesn't.

---

Now that you know that you only need the unordered pairs, no need to iterate `j` from `1` to `ar.length`. Since you need `j > i`, every `j` between `1` and `i` (inclusive) is useless. You can simplify your code to:

```
static int divisibleSumPairs(int n, int k, int[] ar) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<ar.length-1; i++){
      for(int j=i+1; j<ar.length; j++){
            if(((ar[i]+ar[j])%k)==0){
                   count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Yes @Ricola I have read the question again, and it seems that `i<j`, is what they otherwise the result would not have been same. Thanks btw.

Comment: cf. Pomax comment to OP

Comment: Hi, can you please explain this with a simple example taking into a sample small data? That would be SUPER helpful for beginners like me who are in the same boat. Thanks!

Comment: @NKRao let's say your array has 4 (=`length`) elements. The pairs with `i < j` are i= 0:(0,1)(0,2)(0,3) then i=1: (1,2)(2,3) then i=2: (2,3). Notice how `i` goes from `0` to `length-2` and `j` goes from `i+1` to `length-1`. Furthermore, these are unordered pairs as we don't consider (0,1) and (1,0) differently, they are the same pair in this case as the order doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 2):

Wen you do `i = {0 ... 10}` and `j = {1 ... 10}`, then there are (about) 100 cmobinations (of i and j), (about) 50, where i < j and the rest vice versa. So your assumption is wrong, that:

> it is supposedly giving me a wrong answer

...it gives you correctly the wrong answer!  ...since when `a[i] + a[j] % k == 0`, then `a[j] + a[i] % k == 0` also!

If you don't include the `if(i < j)`, you count (the occurrence of pairs ..exactly) doubly.

An (implementation) alternative would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  // ensure i < j via initialization ;)
  for (int j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
    if (((ar[i]+ar[j]) % k) == 0) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
}
```

...to initialize the inner loop with `i + 1` instead of `1`.

---

EDIT:(after getting the question better)

Your assumption, that `a[i] > a[j]` is equivalent with `i > j` OR `j < i`(but not both), is almost correct: except when `a[i] == a[j]`.

Comment: I get the same answer, since the loop follows the pos form 1 only, which is actually `i+1` in this case. You can run my logic and use the `j=1`, you will get the same result. Since I had to compare it with the normal looping system. Doesn't make any changes though. Thanks for the input though

Comment: @Alok that's not true, `1` is not `i+1`. The only reason why it makes no difference is because of your condition `if(i < j)`. I updated my answer also.

Comment: ..ok, now maybe understanding the question better... `a[i] > a[j]`is "almost equivalent" with `i > j` or (vice versa:) ...but you didnt consider the corner case!!!

Comment: @xerx593 : wait what? The two conditions are not equivalent at all. They only are if and only if the array is sorted in strictly increasing order.

Comment: no, not equivalent, @Ricola but for this algorithm...(loop invariant, to count correctly (and exclude duplicates ..as in the original loop))

Comment: Got your point @xerx593, since every time the inner loop will start from 1 only, which is completely wrong. We always have to start off with the next element to the i element.

Comment: ...i understand now, alok's assumption, and why it is wrong :)

Comment: @xerx593 : ok I understand, you mean in this specific case where `i > j` simply means "unordered pair" ? (In the same train of thought, since we only need to count the pairs, the condition `i < j` is equivalent also)

Answer (score 2):

That's my solution in javaScript (Passed all test-cases):

```
function divisibleSumPairs(n, k, ar) {
    let count=0;
    
    for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<n; j++){
            if(i<j){
              if((ar[i]+ar[j])%k===0) count++; 
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Even though it is correct. Better solution would be using `j= i + 1` in second loop that way you are not looping entire array again doing nothing literally and time complexity will increase also

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested in an O(n) solution, here is my C# solution.

```cs
public static int divisibleSumPairs(int n, int k, List<int> ar)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> map = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    int cnt = 0;
    
    foreach (int elem in ar)
    {
        int modulo = elem % k;
        int complement = modulo == 0 ? 0 : k - modulo;
        
        if (map.ContainsKey(complement))
        {
            cnt += map[complement];
        }
        
        if (map.ContainsKey(modulo))
        {
            ++map[modulo];
        }
        else
        {
            map.Add(modulo, 1);
        }
    }
    
    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is using javaScript :

```
 divisibleSumPairs (n, k, ar) => {
  let count = 0;
  ar = ar.map((value, index, arr) => {
    for (let i = index + 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
      if ((value + arr[i]) % k === 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  });
  return count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def divisibleSumPairs(n, k, ar):
    result = 0
    d = {}

    for i in range(n):
        mod = ar[i] % k
        result += d.get(( k - mod ) % k, 0)
        d[mod] = d.get(mod, 0) + 1

    return result
```

solution in O(n)

Answer (score 1):

> **Dart Solution**

```
n = arr.length;
int numberOfDivisiblePairs = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
    if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) % k == 0) {
      numberOfDivisiblePairs++;
    }
  }
}
return numberOfDivisiblePairs;
```

Comment: Nice to see a dart solution man. Great job! Thank you very much for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution in Python 3 (Passed all test-cases):

The itertools.combinations(arr,r) returns the r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable. Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.

```
from itertools import combinations

def divisibleSumPairs(n,ar,k):
    pairs = []
    for com in combinations(ar,2): 
        if sum(com) % k == 0:
            pairs.append(com)
    return len(pairs)


nk = input().split()
n = int(nk[0])
k = int(nk[1])            
ar = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
print(divisibleSumPairs(n,ar,k))
```